# Finding overlap between dictionary values expressed as comma separated integers

Tags: python, dictionary, range, mapping, overlap

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'IDa': '55-88', 'IDb': '55-138', 'IDc': '225-383'}

dict2 = {'IDa': '44-150', 'IDb': '44-127', 'IDc': '44-88'}
```

When the ID is the same between the two dictionaries, and there is an overlap between the values, I store the ID and the two ranges. For now, I was attempting to get the max() and min() functions working, which I was planning on using to compute the overlaps.

To do so, I tried to convert the values of dict1 and dict2 to tuples, so that I could use the max() and min() functions.

```
for k, v in dict1.items():

    conv = tuple([v])
    print(conv)
```

output

```
('55-88',)
 etc
```

what I would need is: (44-129). If I use max() or min() on this output, it prints the range block (shown below).

```
for k, v in dict1.items():

    conv = tuple([v])
    print(max(conv))
```

output

```
  55-88
  55-138
  etc...
```

I am aware the problem might be naive, but I am new to coding and I am trying to solve the issue but I keep getting the same output. If someone could give me some hint or explain what I am doing wrong that would be great.

Comment: How are you getting `('44-129',)` no such value exists in the dict you posted.

Comment: You are not converting the text representation of ranges to actual numbers, nor are you checking the ranges against each other.

Comment: meowgoesthedog thanks! I will try and work on this one.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to extract the respective integers. Then you can "abuse" sets and check the intersections between ranges. If an intersection is not empty it means there is an overlap.

For example:

```
range1 = '45-90'
range2 = '48-93'

range1_start, range1_end = map(int, range1.split('-'))
range2_start, range2_end = map(int, range2.split('-'))

if set(range(range1_start, range1_end)) & set(range(range2_start, range2_end)):
    print('overlap found')
# overlap found
```

Although a naive solution, it will be fairly fast for reasonably sized ranges.

Alternatively you can use the start and end values of both ranges to mathematically check for overlaps but it will require some logic and taking care of some edge cases.